# h2 margin or padding is greater than h3 even if they have same font-size?

Tags: css, html-heading

I'm running into a strange problem.

Trying to style h2 and h3 similar. So they look identical on different pages.

I've ready samples too, please take a look:

http://artvard.com/category.html this h2 posttittle should have exact same margins as -> http://artvard.com/main.html h3 posttittle.

for some strange reason, they have different margin/padding at the top, so spacing looks different.

[image]

I'm running out of ideas on how to solve this :(

Comment: Looks like it's working? I see the same margins in both Firefox and IE8.

Comment: I think this would be better on [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). Voting for migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your CSS you have set your font sizes on the `<a>` elements inside the post titles - this means that the post titles themselves still have differing font sizes, and different line heights, which is where the discrepancy in spacing is coming from.

Try changing

```
h3.posttittle a, h2.posttittle a {
    color:#E95D01;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

to

```
h3.posttittle, h2.posttittle {
    font-size: 16px;
}

h3.posttittle a, h2.posttittle a {
    color:#E95D01;
}
```